while importing below libraries getting error import numpy as np import pandas as pd import matplotlib.pyplot as plt from fer import FER
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 4
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 4 from fer import FER



ImportError: cannot import name 'get_model_proto' from 'tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.iterator_ops' (C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\ops\iterator_ops.py)


Please read How do I ask a good question? and revise your post based on it. Paying special attention to the sections under the headings 'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem' and 'Help others reproduce the problem'.  About the latter, note the advice "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem" and making a minimal, reproducible example. Also look at related questions with high scores and high scoring answers and revise to better match those.
